Generalizations of the intermediated function (metamorph)
Let z1 and z2 be two complex matrices with the same size. The intermediated function is a continuous linear transformation of z1 to z2 with the real parameter 0 ≤ t ≤ 1:
zt = (1-t)z1+tz2.
If the matrices would be integer based and represent gray values this would be a simple image morphing. In my case the complex matrices are coding image coordinates i.e. vector maps. The two matrices are in fact conformal mappings of some initial structure: z1 = f1(z0), z2 = f2(z0).
I am interested in non-trivial generalizations of this weighted sum approach of interpolation/morphing in nonlinear ways. A glimpse of what I have in mind is shown in the continuous transformation of the identity function to the Cayley function [1]. There a non-trivial nonlinear function with sin, cos, sqrt and i elements together with t is derived that transforms z to (z-i)/(z+i) with 0 ≤ t ≤ π/(3*sqrt(3)). But this derivation is much too specific for a general template to transform z1 to z2.
A possible strategy would be the assumption that the intermediated function is a member of a function class F(z1,z2,t) that share the same attributes (this also means that different attribute sets leads to different classes). Followed by the search for other class members (and playing with relaxations of those attributes).
So the first step would be the extraction of necessary attributes from the intermediated function. Assuming 0 ≤ t ≤ 1 the obvious ones are:

F(z1,z2,0) = z1
F(z1,z2,1) = z2

These are examples of the first class of attributes that require only one function evaluation.
A second class of attributes will be related to the sequence of intermediated matrices which means that it require more function evaluations and some kind of distance/similarity measure between matrices (perhaps Frobenius Norm). Such a measure is also computed several times per test case, therefore this attribute class is much more computational expensive.
An example could be the monotonic test of a transformation F(z1,z2,t): Given a discretization of t in n steps T = [ti, i = 1, ...,n] with t1 = 0 and tn = 1 that leads to a list of n matrices I = [zti, i=1,...,n] with zt1 = z1 and ztn = z2.
F(z1,z2,t) would be monotonic if with growing i the similarity to z1 gets smaller and the similarity to z2 gets larger. Or if t1 < t2 then zt1 has a smaller distance to z1 than zt2 to z1: d(z1,zt1) < d(z1,zt2).
Q:What additional attributes could be useful to define such function classes that are easy to test in a kind of symbolic regression search setting?
[1] Jadczyk, Arkadiusz: Continuous Cayley Transform. 2010. http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.org/papers/cayley-2010-02-06.pdf https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Continuous_Cayley_Transform.gif
